# Array manipulation (summing one column by certain group, keeping others the same)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping

I have a table of Logs with the columns `name, duration, type, ref_id`.

I update the table every so often so perhaps it will look like a col of `['bill', 'bob', 'bob', 'jill']` for names, and `[3, 5, 6, 2]` for duration, and `['man', boy', 'boy', 'girl']` for type, and `[1, 2, 2, 3]` for ref_id.

I would like to manipulate my table so that I can add all the durations so that I get a hash or something that looks like this:

```
{'name' => ['bill', 'bob', 'jill'], 'duration' => [3, 11, 2], 'type' => ['man', 'boy', 'girl'], ref_id => [1, 2, 3]}
```

How can I do this?

(for more info--currently I'm doing `Log.sum(:duration, :group => 'name')` which gives me the names themselves as the keys (bill, bob, jill) instead of the column name, with the correct duration sums as their values (3, 11, 2). but then I lose the rest of the data...)

I guess I could manually go through each log and add the name/type/ref_id if it's not in the hash, then add onto the duration.  If so what's the best way to do that?

If you know of good sources on rails array manipulation/commonly used idioms, that would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of notes first.

Your table is not properly normalized. You should split this table into (at least) two: `users`, and `durations`. You should do this for lots of reasons, that's relational databases 101.

Also, the hash you want as a result also doesn't look right, it suggests that you are pre-grouping data to suit your presentation. It's usually more logical to put these results in an array of hashes, than in a hash of arrays.

Now on to the answer:

With your table, you can simply do GROUP BY:

```
SELECT name, type, ref_id, SUM(duration) as duration
FROM logs
GROUP BY name, type, ref_id
```

or, using AR:

```
durations = Log.find(:all,
  :select => 'name, type, ref_id, SUM(duration) as duration',
  :group => 'name, type, ref_id'
)
```

In order to convert this to a hash of arrays, you'd use something like:

```
Hash[
  %w{name, type, ref_id, duration}.map{|f|
    [f, durations.map{|h|
      h.attributes[f]
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: hmm well 'name' really is the log name, I just made it people's names here since I thought it might be easier.  what would the hash you want look like? (this made the most intuitive sense to me so I went with it).  I'm actually pulling this data to make some graphs, (the plugin I'm using takes an array of values to plot, for example,  and another array for x values) so I'm not sure an array of hashes would work? (what did you mean?) but thanks so much for how to do this, works great! (I haven't worked with databases before either...)

Comment: Well, usually there's no reason to convert the data from what `find` method returns, just use the part you need where you need it (typically in a view): if you would want a series of names, you'd use `durations.map{|d| d.name}` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all you need is something like this that spins through all the log entries and collects the results:

```
# Define attributes we're interested in
operate_on = %w[ name duration type ref_id ]

# Create a new hash with placeholder hashes to collect instances
summary = Hash[operate_on.map { |k| [ k, { } ] }]

Log.all.collect do |log|
  operate_on.each do |attr|
    # Flag this attribute/value pair as having been seen
    summary[attr][log.send(attr)] = true
  end
end

# Extract only the keys, return these as a hash
summary = Hash[summary.map { |key, value| [ key, value.keys ] }]
```

A more efficient method would be to do this as several `SELECT DISTINCT(x)` calls instead of instancing so many models.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand if you want to save records from your hash, or you want to query the table and get results back in this form. If you want to get a hash back, then this should work:

```
Log.all.inject({}) do |hash, l|
  hash['name'] ||= []
  hash['duration'] ||= []
  hash['type'] ||= []
  hash['ref_id'] ||= []
  hash['name'] << l.name
  hash['duration'] << l.duration
  hash['type'] << l.type
  hash['ref_id'] << l.ref_id
  hash
end
```

Comment: hmm does hash['duration'] << l.duration accumulate the durations? I'm summing the durations for each log name. btw, I didn't think about saving the records...I guess I could just save the new cumulative log duration every time this happens, then delete the individual records.  would this be a better design?

Comment: @butterywombat No, this solution does not sum the `duration` values.